# RTK Query map request body and params

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I've implemented transforming rtq query response like that:

```
const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'API',
  baseQuery: async (...args) => {
    const { data, meta, error } = await baseQuery(...args)
    const { status } = meta?.response || {}

    return { data: camelize(data), meta, error } as QueryReturnValue
  },
  endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

Now I want to transform the request body and params, to be changed from camelCase to snake_case. I suppose I have to implement it here in the base query, but I don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to do exactly what you're trying to do with a few different apis, so I created this function.  I'm using a different library to do the camel-casing and snake-casing, but otherwise, this should work for you:

```
import { fetchBaseQuery, FetchArgs } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query"
import { BaseQueryApi, QueryReturnValue } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/baseQueryTypes"
import { FetchBaseQueryArgs } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/fetchBaseQuery"
import camelcaseKeys from "camelcase-keys"
import * as snakecaseKeys from "snakecase-keys"


export const fetchCasingBaseQuery = (args: FetchBaseQueryArgs) => {
  const bq = fetchBaseQuery(args)
  const ret = (async (fetchArgs: FetchArgs | string, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}) => {
    console.log(fetchArgs, api, extraOptions)
    if (typeof fetchArgs != 'string') {
      if (fetchArgs.params) {
        fetchArgs.params = snakecaseKeys(fetchArgs.params, { deep: true })
      }
      if (fetchArgs.body) {
        fetchArgs.body = snakecaseKeys(fetchArgs.body, { deep: true })
      }
    }
    const { data, meta, error } = await bq(fetchArgs, api, extraOptions)
    return { data: camelcaseKeys(data as any[] | Record<string, any>, { deep: true }), meta, error } as QueryReturnValue<unknown, unknown, {}>
  }) as typeof bq
  return ret
}
```

(I'm using typescript - open to any suggestions for how to handle the types better!)

Then you can use this function to substitute for `fetchBaseQuery`.

```
export const reportsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'reports',
  baseQuery: fetchCasingBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/reports' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getReportById: builder.query<Report, string>({
      query: (id) => `/${id}`
    }),
    getReportsByPage: builder.query<Report[], ListRequest<Report>>({
      query: ({ page, pageSize, orderBy, orderAsc }) => ({
        url: 'list',
        params: {
          page,
          pageSize,
          orderBy,
          orderAsc: orderAsc && 1 || 0
        }
      })
    }),
    ...
```